# Play 2.0 Nested forms: generate <input id="email"> instead of <input id="user_email">

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, nested-forms, strip

[Posted this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/fX0U_ftgW4k) to Play user group; I account for the sole view, so hoping to get a view, or perhaps even an answer ;-)

Nested forms are great, but there's one glitch that adds boilerplate to either javascript or scala templates.

For example, given:

```
@inputText(field = _form("user.email"),
    '_label-> "Email Address*",
    'class-> "required email",
    'placeholder-> "jdoe@gmail.com"
)
```

the generated input field is something like:

```
<input id="user_email" name="user.email" ...>
```

Now, when you want to validate the email address client-side you then have to reference DOM id: `$('#user_email')`

Where `$('#email')` would be more natural.

I know I can set the id attrib manually in the template but would prefer to, by default, have the nested name (user in this case) stripped out from the id attrib.

Looking in github [views helper directory](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper), I am not finding where I can get access to the generated id (i.e. which file I need to overload and how).

Anyone know how to pull this off and/or have a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where the field's ID is auto-generated:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L274

There's not really any way you can override that behaviour, but you could write your own `@inputText` helper that strips the "user_" part from the ID when generating the HTML.

Basically copy-paste the [default helper](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputText.scala.html) and replace

```
<input type="text" id="@id" ...
```

with your own code, e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="@processFieldId(id)" ...
```

or (untested!):

```
<input type="text" id="@(id.split('_').last)" ...
```

Then just import your custom helper in your template, and use it just like you would use `@inputText`.

Comment: +1 thanks, thought it might be difficult to override. Ideally this would work for input, select, textarea, radiogroup, etc., so nipping it in the bud right at the source would be the way to go if possible. As I said, I can just manually add the id attrib for nested forms, but in the spirit of DRY, thought I'd ask the question

Comment: Also I just noticed that the `FieldConstructor` references the field's ID as well, so if you go the route that I suggested then you will have to fix the ID there as well. Pretty messy.

Comment: indeed, no bigs, have a more important issue that I'll post in a bit: templates lacking generics, how do you pass Form[User] to the field snippet include when it needs to reference "user.email", "user.password", etc.? catch 22